# Hide Label, But Show Placeholder at the same time?

Tags: css, html

I have a form with this code:

```
<div id="zipcode-label" class="f-label"><label for="zipcode" class="required">Zip code</label></div>
<div id="first-element" class="f-element"><input type="tel" class='rounder' size="5" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="Your Zip code" value="" tabindex="2" pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="Five digit zipcode" required></div>
```

I want to hide the label part (I don't want to delete it), so I tried using `style="display:none"`, but for some reason it also hides the placeholder of the field.

Any way to resolve this?

Comment: What part exactly are you trying to hide? Do you want the text within the label to be hidden (e.g. "Zip code") but have the input element still visible? You might consider posting exactly where you are attempting to add the "display: none" style as well.

Comment: Could we see your CSS?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using some kind of framework (based solely on class names like `"f-label"`) so there's probably something else going on you're not telling us about.

Comment: sorry guys, problem was a validator script that caused the placeholders to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding the `label` with `display:none;` should not effect the placeholder of the input:

```css
label[for="zipcode"] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="zipcode-label" class="f-label"><label for="zipcode" class="required">Zip code</label></div>
<div id="first-element" class="f-element"><input type="tel" class='rounder' size="5" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="Your Zip code" value="" tabindex="2" pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="Five digit zipcode" required></div>
```

Comment: Then maybe my problem is different, since I just noticed that even if I don't hide it, I don't see the placeholder. I see placeholder only if I delete the first DIV in my code, what's the problem?

Comment: Please update your question with code that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
.f-label label{display:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#zipcode-label {
  display: none;
}
```

works for me in JSFiddle, but I don't have your internal or external stylesheets so that may be a huge part of the equation